# referencing <p> elements that has a name attribute with the value mytext

Tags: css, css-selectors

So this is what my book says:

For CSS:

```
p[name^=”my”] { color: #ff0000 }
p[name$=”my”] { color: #00ff00 }
p[name*=”my”] { color: #0000ff }
```

this is what my html says:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p class="my1111">first</p>
<p class="11my11">second</p>
<p class="1111my">third</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Shouldn't first be red, second be green, and third be blue? I even tried adding p{color:#000000;} as the first line in css with no results. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/RMZzb/)

```
p[class^="my"] { color: #ff0000 }
p[class$="my"] { color: #00ff00 }
p[class="11my11"] { color: #0000ff }
```

note: also you have written quote as `”my”` should be `"my"`

Comment: Ok. So NAME was apparently a placeholder. *sigh*. Awesome. I can't believe you guys/girls can answer these things so fast. Thanks a mil :):):)